# How to maintain user state in website that allows Single signon

Tags: database, single-sign-on, state

I am making a web app that allows users to register and login. As an extra feature, I want to add the functionality of allowing users to sign in using their Gmail via Single Signon.
The question is how do I go about maintaining the state of users who signed in via Gmail? Do I create a database entry for them as well? How could the schema look like because unlike the users who signed up via regular process,these users would not have provided their password.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

One way is to use social login as means to simplify the registration process  - by pre-populating data returned from Google into the registration form. In such mode you would always also generate regular username/password account. This enables you to e.g. add feature which allows your users to add/change social login after they have already registered. Schema would then contain common user data for all users + some users would contain an attribute with their Google account ID (or other IDs if you decide to add more in the future).

Another approach is to allow only one type of authentication - either internal username/password or social login. You could still keep the schema as above - one record per user, but in addition you would include an attribute which differentiates between internal/federated users. Each combination of userID + type (internal/federated) should then be unique. This approach would still allow your users to customize their profile (e.g. change their name, ...) in the application, but they would be unable to update the authentication mechanism. The password field would be simply null for the federated users.

In case you don't need to populate any data about users who authenticated with social login (e.g. they're just accessing a simple chat interface and you just want to get their name, or you don't need complete profile until user tries to perform certain operation - like complete an order), you could also completely skip any account creation and "forget" the user once they logout.